# CommunityToolkit.MVVM The namespace 'namespace' already contains a definition for 'type'

Tags: c#, mvvm, maui

I want to use MVVM in .NET MAUI and I started with CommunityToolkit.MVVM.

I created a view model and get the following error:

`The namespace 'MyApp.ViewModels' already contains a definition for 'ProfilePopupViewModel '`

Here is the view model:

```
public class ProfilePopupViewModel : ObservableRecipient
    {
        private Profile Profile;

        [ObservableProperty]
        private string id;
        [ObservableProperty]
        private string name;
        [ObservableProperty]
        private DateOnly birthDate;
        [ObservableProperty]
        private int work;
    }
```

Thank you!

Markus

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your type needs to be partial:

```
public partial class ProfilePopupViewModel : ObservableRecipient
{
    [ObservableProperty]
    private string id;
    // ...
}
```

The MVVM Toolkit contains a [Source Generator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/roslyn-sdk/source-generators-overview). This works by picking up on those `ObservableProperty` attributes you added, and generating C# code which is added to the compilation.

For your class, it will generate another [partial class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/partial-classes-and-methods) which contains properties corresponding to your `[ObservableProperty]` fields. Something like:

```
partial class ProfilePopupViewModel
{
    public string Id
    {
        get => id;
        set
        {
            if (id != value)
            {
                id = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("Id");
            }
        }
    }

    // ...
}
```

In order for this to compile, your `ProfilePopupViewModel` also needs to be marked as `partial`.

Answer (score 2):

This seems to be a known error with .NET 6.0.302 and source generators like the on in Toolkit.MVVM (see https://github.com/dotnet/wpf/issues/6792)